# Find End of Block Marker Flash ByteArray with Deflate Compressed Data

Tags: sockets, apache-flex, websocket, arrays, deflate

I have some data that is sent over a web socket to a flash client.  That data is compressed using Java Deflate class before it's sent to the client.

I'm getting a

> Error #2058: There was an error decompressing the data

When the data coming across the wire is large and calling the deflate method of byteArray

Deflate code on server (Scala):

```
def deflate(str:String):Array[Byte] = {
    val data = str.getBytes
    val deflater = new Deflater(9, true)
    deflater.setInput(data)

    val outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length)
    deflater.finish
    val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
    while(!deflater.finished) {
      val count = deflater.deflate(buffer)
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count)
    }
    outputStream.close
    val output = outputStream.toByteArray
    output
  }
```

Send to the client:

```
def sendToClient(message:String) {
      println("original message length: " + message.length)
      val compressed = deflate(message)
      //wrap the compressed data in base64 encoded string because of a requirement for this on the client          
      val toClient = Base64.encodeBase64String(compressed)
      clientConnection.sendMessage(toClient)
    }
```

Client:

```
//read the data into the ByteArray
while(socket.bytesAvaialble > 4) {
    //unwrap base64 encoded stuff
    myByteArray[position] = socket.readUnsignedByte();
}

//inflate the data in the ByteArray
myByteArray.inflate();
```

When data the data coming across the websocket is large, the call to inflate fails, because not all of the data is there.  I would like to figure out how to make sure that all of the data is there, before I call inflate()

According to [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt) (page 9), I should be looking for a block header to determine when all of the compressed content has arrived.

How do I look for that header with the ByteArray API?

Comment: I don't see where you are decoding the Base64 encoding.  Also that can't be your actual client code, since you misspelled "Available".

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find the end of a deflate stream is to inflate it.  The end is not evident by simply looking, for example, for some bit or byte pattern.  All of the tables and codes in the deflate stream would need to be decoded in sequence until the end is encountered.

I can't speak for the API you are using, but normally the interface to zlib permits feeding an inflate object a piece of the deflate stream at a time.  The inflator will tell you when it gets to the end of the compressed data, and you will be left with the unused bytes after the deflate stream.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've updated the question to be a bit more explanatory.  I have used the nowrapper parameter for the deflate call (see server appended server code).